# Yii2 user model with relational tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to Yii and I have problem with its User and login system .
I should use 3 tables for login check but when I use custom query I face

`"Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterface, ActiveQuery given"`

my tables are like :

- `user : user_id, name, family, birthday, ...`
- `email : email_user_fk, email_addr, email_active, email_cdt`
- `passwd : passwd_user_fk, passwd_hashed, passwd_active, passwd_cdt`

and my query is like :
`SELECT 
  user.user_id, email.email_addr, email.email_active, 
  passwd.passwd_hashed, passwd_passwd_active , ...
FROM user
  JOIN email ON user.user_id = email.email_user_fk
  JOIN passwd ON user.user_id = passwd.passwd_user_fk
WHERE
  email.email_addr = :email`

Is there any Idea ,Please ??

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public static function primaryKey(){
        return 'user_id';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function find

    Identity($id)
        {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['email' => $username]);
    }

    public static function findByEmail($email)
    {
        return User::find()
            ->joinWith(['emails'])
            ->where("email.email_address = 'me@mail.com' ")
            ->one();
    }

    public static function findByMobile($email)
    {
        return User::find()
            ->joinWith(['mobiles'])
            ->where("mobile.mobile_address = '0931515124' ")
            ->one();
    }


    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        $parts = explode('_', $token);
        $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_name', 'user_family', 'user_birthday'], 'required'],
            [['user_gender', 'city_id_fk', 'user_status'], 'integer'],
            [['user_birthday', 'user_cdt'], 'safe'],
            [['user_name'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['user_family'], 'string', 'max' => 48],
            [['user_tel', 'user_postcode'], 'string', 'max' => 12],
            [['user_address'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
            [['user_profile_image', 'user_cover_image'], 'string', 'max' => 256]
        ];
    }



    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Email::className(), ['email_user_id_fk' => 'user_id']);
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getMobiles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Mobile::className(), ['mobile_user_id_fk' => 'user_id']);
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPasswds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Passwd::className(), ['passwd_user_id_fk' => 'user_id']);
    }

}
```

Comment: show your User Mode or the model where is defined the login() method

Comment: @scaisEdge - for example I want to define the function findByEmail() but email column doesn't store in User table. email has separated table with one to many relation  . I need to join User table with Email table where email_active is true

Comment: In your code seem you don't implement the `user interface`  correctly.  seem there isn't the `findIndentity()` method. An interfaces's implementetion must implement all the interface method.

Comment: @scaisEdge, I have this method , the 4th function :)

Comment: Attention in your code the 4th function is find non findIdentity. Is  a typo or is an coding error?.

Answer (score 1):

What this error is showing is that when you execute Yii::$app->user->login() at some point you must pass a User object that implements identity interface as a parameter (and it seems you are passing another type of object).

What this method does is allow you to save the information from the user after logging. First the user provides a username, then it has to retrieve info for this username from the database and instatiate a user object with this info. This is the object that you have to pass to the Yii::$app->user->login() function.

Read about the User class [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html).

and find a good sample [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57493-yii-2-login-from-db-create-user/).